# Do compilers read the code and optimize the random memory allocations?

Tags: c, compiler-optimization

I have a code where I declare a pointer (named "*removed*") in type of a struct called *DLINKED_LIST_NODE*.

```
DLINKED_LIST_NODE curr = dlinked_list_goto_idx(list, idx, false);
DLINKED_LIST_NODE removed;

if(curr->next != NULL)
    removed = curr->next;
else {
    printf("Error @ dlinked_list_remove: No such index.\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

**dlinked_list_goto_idx** just returns the starting point of the double linked list. So removed will be the head of the list.

When I debug the code, **dlinked_list_goto_idx** returns the list itself (which is the starting node) and I can see it's address. Then removed is declared and again I see the address of it.

Before I execute the `removed = curr->next;` block I see that the address of **removed** is actually identical to `curr->next`.

Does compiler do this to optimize the code or I cannot see an obvious stuff?

This is how it looks when I debug to the point where **removed** is declared.
https://pasteboard.co/HHe6eQE.png

And this is the debug screen where you can see the `curr->next`.
https://pasteboard.co/HHe7dF8.png

Comment: Source level debugging code with optimisation on is like taking LSD. Do not do this.

Comment: There's lots of ways this could be a coincidence. The only way to be sure is to examine the assembly code. What compiler and flags are you using? Do you see this happening with a small demonstration program?

Comment: Does the situation change if you reorder the variable declarations?

Comment: Could you show us how you're checking that the address of `removed` is the same as `curr->next`?

Comment: This does not appear to be an optimization issue. If I'm interpreting what you've said correctly, it appears that `curr->next` has been set to the point to the head of the list. This could be intentional, or it could be a bug.

Comment: @Schwern I have added the debug screen.

Comment: @Schwern and I am using Cmake with CLion.

Comment: @bobjarvis `curr->next` is intentionally meant to be head of the list. But removed doesnt supposed to have that address as it declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're compiling with anything except `-O0` or its equivalent - i.e. "no optimizations" - the compiler may very well be rewriting your code as:

```
register DLINKED_LIST_NODE curr = dlinked_list_goto_idx(list, idx, false);
register DLINKED_LIST_NODE removed = curr->next;

if(removed == 0) {
    printf("Error @ dlinked_list_remove: No such index.\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

In other words, it may have chosen to pull `removed = curr->next` up to the point of declaration and then test for NULL (0) against the register var `removed` because testing the contents of a register for zero is generally a pretty cheap test, and may in fact not even require a test if the zero flag is set by the assignment, which it might be depending on the architecture.

The point here is - don't debug optimized code, unless the non-optimized version works and the optimized version doesn't (which can happen due to various issues).

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you. I guess that's what really happened.